# Order detail_route with ordering query parameter using Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

In a `detail_route` method like the following, how would I support ordering of the events using the `ordering` query parameter like this:

http://localhost.com/items/123/events?ordering=EventDateTime

```
class ItemViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    queryset = Item.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ItemSerializer
    filter_backends = (
        filters.OrderingFilter
    )
    ordering_fields = ('Label')

    @detail_route()
    def events(self, request, pk=None):
        item = self.get_object()
        events = item.events.all()
        page = self.paginate_queryset(events)
        if page is not None:
            serializers = EventSerializer(page, many=True, context={'request': request})
            return self.get_paginated_response(serializers.data)
        serializers = EventSerializer(events, many=True, context={'request': request})
        return Response(serializers.data)
```

I've tried the following but nothing gets sorted:

```
@detail_route()
def events(self, request, pk=None):
    item = self.get_object()
    events = filters.OrderingFilter().filter_queryset(request, item.events.all(), self)
    page = self.paginate_queryset(events)
    if page is not None:
        serializers = EventSerializer(page, many=True, context={'request': request})
        return self.get_paginated_response(serializers.data)
    serializers = EventSerializer(events, many=True, context={'request': request})
    return Response(serializers.data)
```

Comment: You can specify `ordering_fields = ('Lable', 'EventDatetime',)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As soup boy suggested. You need to add EventDateTime to ordering_fields in the ItemViewSet.